# Using the 'before-quit' event in electron (atom-shell)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, electron

I have a application which needs to make an API call before it quits (something like logout). As I still need access to some app data (redux store) for the API call so I decided to listen to the 'before-quit' event on app.

I tried the following code:

```
import {remote} from 'electron';
let loggedout = false;

remote.app.on('before-quit', (event) => {
  if (loggedout) return; // if we are logged out just quit.
  console.warn('users tries to quit');

  // prevent the default which should cancel the quit
  event.preventDefault();

  // in the place of the setTimout will be an API call
  setTimeout(() => {
    // if api call was a success
    if (true) {
      loggedout = true;
      remote.app.quit();
    } else {
      // tell the user log-out was not successfull. retry and quit after second try.
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

The event never seems to fire or preventing shutdown does not work.
When I replace `before-quit` with `browser-window-blur` the event **does** fire and the code seems to work.

For reference I use Electron 1.2.8 (Due to some dependencies I cannot upgrade). I've double checked and `before-quit` event was already [implemented](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.2.8/docs/api/app.md#event-before-quit) in that version.

Any Ideas why this event does not seem to be fired?

Thanks in advance and happy holidays!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, this was my solution:

In renderer:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
window._saved = false
window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
    if (!window.saved) {
        callSaveAPI(() => {
            // success? quit the app
            window._saved = true
            ipcRenderer.send('app_quit')
            window.onbeforeunload = null
        })
    }
    e.returnValue = false
}
```

In main:

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
// listen the 'app_quit' event
ipcMain.on('app_quit', (event, info) => {
    app.quit()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems which prevented the code from working:

1. Somehow the 'before-quit' event does not fire in the rerender process. (not main.js).
2. Once I moved the eventlistener into the main-process preventing the default did not stop the windows from closing. This can only be done through adding an `window.onbeforeunload` function which returns false. Like suggested in [this thread](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-catch-the-event-of-clicking-the-app-windows-close-button-in-electron-app/21425).

One caveat is that the return statement of `onbeforeunload` does not get updated. In my case I first returned false (to prevent the closing of the window). The second time it did not return false but it kept preventing the closing of the window.

I got around that through overriding the `window.onbeforeunload` with a new function which did not return false.